# php simple xml phrase multi-level tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

It is possible that with `simpleXML` to parse foreach "categories" -> all the "subCategories1" nodes (not only the first from each "categories" ) ?

**Example**: need to go in subcategories1 after in subcategories2 after in subcategories3, come back in subcategories2->subcategories3, if there are no more subcategories2 go to subcategories1, if there are no subcategories1 in this categories node do to the next one.

```
<xml>
<categories>
    <tag11>value</tag11>
    <tag12>value</tag12>
    <subCategories1> 
        <tag21>value</tag21>
        <tag22>value</tag22>
        <subCategories2>
            <!-- ........ -->
            <tag31>....</tag31>
        </subCategories2>
    </subCategories1>
</categories>

<categories>
    <subCategories1> 
        <!-- ............... -->
    </subCategories1> 
    <subCategories1> 
        <!-- ............... -->
    </subCategories1> 
</categories>

<!-- ....... -->

<categories>
    <!-- ............ -->
</categories>

</xml>
```

```php
foreach($xml->Categories as $categories){
   foreach ($categories->SubCategories1 as $cat => $value){ 
       //this took only the first SubCategories1 node from all Categories tag...
   }
}
```

p.s. my english is a little bit rusty.just to be clear I need to go into first "categories" tag, here to go into "subcategory1" here "subcategory2" here all "subcategoory3" go back one level in the next "subcategory2" if exist..if not go down another level in "subcategory1" if exist do the same rutine else go to the next "categories" tag.

Comment: Are those subcategory elements really numbered?

Comment: The `foreach` loop you posted at the end should work fine - the outer loop will give you every `<Categories>` element in your XML document, and the inner loop will give you every `<SubCategories1>` element within each of those.

Comment: for hakre -yes; for IMSoP: the inner foreach will take only the first Subcategories1 from all "categories" node... the problem is that each "categories" node have different number of Subcategories1  nodes. I don't think that it is possible to work this out with simple xml.. maybe with DOMxml?

Comment: @BoboBob I think there must be something else wrong: that foreach loop works fine for me http://codepad.viper-7.com/ngqnJB

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with DOMxml :)

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($destinationFile);
$categories = $xml->getElementsByTagName("Categories");
foreach( $categories as $category ){
    //..............
    foreach( $category->getElementsByTagName("SubCategories1") as $subcategory1 ){
        //...............
        foreach( $subcategory1->getElementsByTagName("SubCategories2") as $subcategory2 ){
            //............
            foreach( $subcategory2->getElementsByTagName("SubCategories3") as $subcategory3 ){
                ......
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `foreach( $category->getElementsByTagName("SubCategories1") as $subcategory1 )` will do exactly the same as `foreach( $category->SubCategories1 as $subcategory1 )` would if you used SimpleXML.

Comment: So, there is no solution for `simplexml_load_file` **?**